# Switch where conditions in a SQL statement based on data

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need a query to switch in the `where` clause depending on dynamic data.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM DOGS 
     WHERE DOG_ID ='1234' ) x, ANIMALS y

IF X.DOG_ID != '3456' THEN  --  SO HERE WHERE CONDITION SWITCH BASE ON DATA FROM DOGS WHICH ID IS '1234'
    WHERE X.DOG_ID = Y.ANIMAL_ID AND (SOME OTHER CONDITION) 
ELSE 
    WHERE X.DOG_ID = Y.ANIMAL_ID
```

My `if` condition would not be from the result set.

Is it possible to switch in a `where` clause with SQL like above?

Comment: How about just using `OR`? Such as `WHERE (X.DOG_ID = Y.ANIMAL_ID AND X.DOG_TYPE = Y.STUFF) OR (X.DOG_ID != Y.ANIMAL_ID AND X.CAT_TYPE = Y.THINGS)`

Comment: @MikeD. Agreed. CASE expressions as join conditions are horrible!

Comment: Could you explain what you want to get as the query result (not how you want it to be implemented)?

Comment: @MikeD.Sorry Please see my question again. in that if Condition is not from any result set

Answer (score 2):

Just nest `AND` and `OR` conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   DOGS 
        WHERE  DOG_ID ='1234') x, 
       ANIMALS y
WHERE  (X.DOG_ID != '3456' AND X.DOG_ID = Y.ANIMAL_ID /*AND (SOME OTHER CONDITION)*/)
       OR 
       (X.DOG_ID = Y.ANIMAL_ID)
```

Notice that you could also be benifited by a [`CASE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions004.htm) perhaps? Check out the docs for more info.

Finally, it seems to me you're actually after a `JOIN`, perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   DOGS 
        WHERE  DOG_ID ='1234') x, 
       JOIN ANIMALS y ON x.DOG_ID = y.ANIMAL_ID
WHERE  (X.DOG_ID != '3456' /*AND (SOME OTHER CONDITION)*/)
```

Comment: Much better! (And would be even better if you converted to modern, explicit JOIN syntax!)

Comment: @jarlh Agreed. Code from the question isn't quite clear enough though to create a relevant real JOIN example though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the `CASE` method

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM DOGS WHERE DOG_ID ='1234' ) X, ANIMALS y
WHERE CASE WHEN X.DOG_ID != Y.ANIMAL_ID 
           THEN X.DOG_ID = Y.ANIMAL_ID AND (SOME OTHER CONDITION) 
           ELSE X.DOG_ID = Y.ANIMAL_ID 
      END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ANSI JOIN

```
select x.*,y.* from dogs as x inner join animals y
on 
( 
(x.dog_id != y.animal_id and x.dog_id = y.animal_id and (some other condition))
       or x.dog_id = y.animal_id
)
where dog_id ='1234'
```